# External linkage to a webpage or pdf document: what humans prefer to link?

Tags: backlinks

Does somebody have an answer, maybe even data-based: which asset is more preferred to be linked, a web page URL, or a pdf document?

Yes, it could depend on the content of both. But let us talk about the following example:

- There is a sequence of some (4-7) articles on different facets of the same topic,
- And a pdf document containing all articles.

I'm trying to validate the following hypothesis:

> *In the case of article series, it is better to earn backlinks to create a pdf document with all articles inside: because a pdf document
> earns more backlinks than an URL, where the series starts*.

The antithesis would be:

> *article series earns more backlinks: because every article as a series part could earn backlinks*.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred is relative because it requires us to know what it is important to you or who is asking the question.  Their are benefits to both.  As an example, if you link to HTML it gives you much more flexibility to change what a user sees when they come back, it's more work but more flexible.  A PDF on the other hand has all the information in one spot, but people might not trust a link to the a PDF as much due to PDF's being historically insecure.  You're also not confined by either, you can use both with a HTML page with the content being the base and include a link to the PDF there (as long as you don't have any issue keeping the information up to sync if you change one).  But... on the PDF side, if it's highly useful niche info for someone they might want to save it (or print it, which people still do) and that's nice.

As per backlinks if you're talking about SEO (speaking towards Google), I don't know that one is preferred to the other.  The most important thing is that you have legitimate back links and that they are coming from reputable sources (not somewhere like comment spam).  If you signup for Google Search Console they will show you all of the backlinks they know about which is useful.

Comment: If you provide each article separately as their own topic, you have the possibility of getting more backlinks. And each of those pages can link to the PDF if they want the whole thing to read later on a larger screen or to print out.